# Greenplum PXF JDBC Parallel insert

Tags: greenplum

When inserting data to jdbc pxf table from gp table:

```
insert into <pxf jdbc target> 
select * from <gp table>
```

does it work in parallel on all PXF instances with many connections to external RDBMS, or on single PXF instance like when selecting from JDBC source without partitioning?

GP Version 6.17

Answer (score 0):

It will be in parallel on all PXF instances.

Answer (score 0):

As per gpdb documentation, for all load and unload operation in HDFS/S3, queries would be executed in parallel.

Reference: https://docs.greenplum.org/6-10/admin_guide/external/g-external-tables.html

Below is the quote from their documentation.

> External tables access external files from within the database as if
> they are regular database tables. External tables defined with the
> gpfdist/gpfdists, pxf, and s3 protocols utilize Greenplum parallelism
> by using the resources of all Greenplum Database segments to load or
> unload data. The pxf protocol leverages the parallel architecture of
> the Hadoop Distributed File System to access files on that system. The
> s3 protocol utilizes the Amazon Web Services (AWS) capabilities.